# Is creating new phtml is allowed in magento go?

Tags: magento, magento-go

Is creating/adding new phtml is allowed in magento go? Please let me know as I am new to magento go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not add any phtml file in magento go, magento go has not access of any file structure.

Besides you can only change in your theme css or add js code in design configuration Miscellaneous Scripts option.